# How calculate probability of function of random variable

Tags: probability

I’m trying to solve an academic exercise in the form of “compute $P[f(X)>0]$ where $f$ is a polynomial(second degree) and $X$ is normally distributed with known mean and stdv.”
I’m familiar with the $Z$ reduction of the normal distribution but can’t figure out the solution neither on my school material.

In particular $f(x)$ is $X^2-3X-4$, $u=3.5$ and $d=2$.
I tried $(1-p[x-1])*(1-p[x<4])$ and applying z=(mean-a)/stdv but this leads to the wrong result using the tables

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

$$x^2-3x-4=(x+1)(x-4)$$

It is positive if $x<-1$ or $x>4$.

Hence you should compute $P(X < -1)+P(X>4).$